# How to return a string and use it in another static void?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create two methods. The first one will return a string and the other one will use the string that the first method returned. At least that's what I'm trying to do...

```
public string Name()
{
    string x = "I need help"
    return x;
}
```

```
static void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

But it keeps saying that the string `x` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Semicolon? `string x = "I need help";`

Comment: ^ and then `Console.WriteLine(Name());` in `Print`. Or to break it down: `string x = Name()` then `Console.WriteLine(x);`. You should probably read about [Scope of Variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/).

Comment: x is a local variable in one function and is used in another function that does not know anything about it. You should review the very basics of C#

Comment: Oh and you need to either store somewhere the returned string from `Name()`, for example make a variable inside your class

Comment: Unless the first method is going to have a logic of its own to execute, you don't need a method just for creating a string. But if it is going to, you need to set a string in the second method to store the one from the first. Something like `string y = Name(); Console.WriteLine(y);`. Methods have contexts of their own, that's why the error message.

Comment: You also need parentheses in your Print declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string Name()
{
    string x = "I need help";
    return x;
}
public static void Print()
{
    string x = Name();
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first method should be static too , otherwise you can not call a non static method in a static method. So you can do like this:

```
public static string Name()
{
 string x = "I need help"; // You forgot a ; at your code 
 return x;
}
static void Print
{
  Console.WriteLine(Name());
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, its a code issue the OP posted anyways. Not sure why anyone didn't mention the missing `;` in their answers.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thanks , I just copy pasted from original question without attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string Name()
{
    string x = "I need help";
    return x;
}
static void Print(string x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

You would use it like:

```
string name = Name();
Print(name);
```

Try it out here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/20HVyh

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
public static string Name()
{
   string x = "I need help";
   return x;
}

public static void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Name());
}
```